# IIS 10 on WinServer 2019 is loading asp.net pages very slow even on subsequent loads

Tags: iis-10

My question has nothing to do with the initial page loads. My ASP.NET Web Site is running very slow, on IIS 10. Even when I refresh the page after a load, it takes minutes. What do I need to check?

1. `Application Initialization Module` is installed and running
2. App Pool is using `Classic` managed Pipeline mode and has `Start-Mode` set to `AlwaysRunning`
3. `Preload Enabled` in Website's setting is set to true

The same application runs fine on another server running older WinServer and IIS 8. What do I need to check?

Comment: Is the server spec comparable? Does it make any DB/external calls? Is it a VPS? Does Resource Monitor show any resource bottleneck during the request/idling?

Answer (score 0):

This is embarrassing. Posting this answer so I find my own question the next time I run into this again, **or someone else runs into this**. My application on the other server where it runs, has caching configured so all the database pulls are cached. This new server has no caching set up. Those pulls are so slow, I am finally getting the hang of it.